# Getting rid of "undefined index" in one line without duplication

Tags: php

I am processing the result of a *GROUP BY* query which does not produce result for all the permutation of constants. It obviously gives an "Undefined Index" notice which I want to get of.

Of course I could use `isset` but it would mean duplication of code (of the index). An other way would be to use a variable to store the index, but it would mean every such line of code is now two line. I like the readability of this line of code.

```
$stat->setMapped($companyStats["Account"][mypackage_MyClass::$STATUS_ACCEPTED]);
```

Is there any way (except the error operator `@` to avoid this notice)?

Comment: So you will end up calling `$stat->setMapped(NULL)` in cases where you don't have the index?

Comment: Is readability important or correctness/bug free code important?

Comment: @lanzz Yet, that is acceptable. I also could use the php way `0+NULL` to where I explicitly need a number.

Comment: @josnidhin I would say both :)

Comment: I'd go the `@` way in your case, I don't see the need for a different solution.

Comment: My suggestion is dont use '@' as it will suppress any error.

Comment: I had many problem with @ before so I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with an array that has all the keys defined and then merge your array into it. The result will have your values where they are defined and null (or whatever defaults you set) where they were not.

```
$allTheKeysYouWant = array('key1' => null, 'key2' => null, ...);
$keysFilled = array_merge($allTheKeysYouWant, $yourArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the setMapped function declaration, accept the parameter by reference, i.e.

```
function setMapped(&$companyStats) {
    if (isset($companyStats)) {
         ....
```

Comment: That would work, but it would be a bit of an overkill to do in a setter function.